# WordPress add_action style arguments works but changes admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, class, wordpress-theming

I've made a code so you can easily add a style sheet to the site, this is for our framework.

It works but if I use this the CSS changes the dashboard layout either? Same with customizer, if I don't use this method, but just a normal wp enqueue it works but that's not what I want.

```
    class theme_setup{
        function main_css_setup($css) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/'.$css.'.css' );
        }
        function add_css_main($css){
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'main_css_setup'),10,1 );
            do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $css );
        }
    }
$theme_setup = new theme_setup();
$theme_setup->add_css_main('main');
```

**Dashboard change:**
[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ96y.png)
[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26JiD.png)

I think it has something to do with the `do_action`, I searched on my best behave, but without any luck.

I'm using the '`do_action`' to pass the argument that the user gives with the `add_css_main`, I know I can use global variables, but these are "static", and that will make the idea be gone of a flexible function.

> Update:

```
function themename_custom_logo_setup($height,$width) {
    $defaults = array(
        'height'      => $height,
        'width'       => $width,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'flex-width'  => true,
        'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
}

    function add_custom_logo($width,$height){
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this, 'themename_custom_logo_setup' ),10,2);
    do_action( 'after_setup_theme', $height,$width);
}

$theme_setup->add_custom_logo(88,250);
```

Does work, but the variables are not even passed at al.

Comment: and why you're using `do_action`?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan To pass the argument, can't find any other way that works, expect.. making a global variable, but then the point of the functions is gone.

Comment: pass argument using your class properties

Comment: As i said, i don't wanna use variable or global variables cause this will take away the "flexible" part.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Saw your answer, and yes it works 2, but.. if i use the add_css_main more then once, only the last one works..

Comment: yes, your're right. the problem, as I mentioned in the deleted answer, is your handler. you should made it dinamyc( change on any call ). but I liked the answer of @brasofilo, that's why deleted my one

Comment: I know, i like his answer 2, but the same methode is not a fix for example: "Website logo width/height", cause that is a change inside the customizer, and the customizer is a "is_admin - true". @SamvelAleqsanyan

Comment: @brasofilo True, i agree with you, but what should be the best way to combine these?

Comment: oh, sorry, the customizer **runs** on the backend.... then the problem lies inside your CSS classes names and such, no?

Comment: The customizer is a "is_admin", so it will not work, and on the other hand why use is_admin at all.

Its not like css, its just a width/height,

Comment: replace this line `wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/'.$css.'.css' );`

Comment: with `wp_enqueue_style( $css, get_template_directory_uri().'/css/'.$css.'.css' );`

Comment: this is not good solution, because the handlers should be unique. and would be good minimum to add some prefix to handlers

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan another hero, same with brasofilo

Comment: glad to help. accept his answer as right

Comment: @pieterbernarnd, I rolled your question back to its last state. You should not add new questions inside this question after solving it. You have to ask a new one. Check the [faq] in case of doubts. Good luck!

Comment: This is the answer that @Samvel posted and deleted, maybe it has the solution to your new problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DdQ8.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should avoid loading the CSS with [this conditional](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) <sup>(maybe apply it somewhere else in your code)</sup>:

```
function add_css_main($css){
    if( !is_admin() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'main_css_setup'),10,1 );
        do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $css );
    }
}
```

Comment: ps: that `do_action` you're using may not be doing what you think it is... Did you read this? [Actions and filters are NOT the same thing…](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/)

Comment: If you don't want to load a CSS file on the backend, `is_admin` is the way to solve the problem. If you need to load a CSS on the backend, you have to make sure your class names and elements don't conflict with WordPress own CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your help already, you're a hero, but.. 

I added a new update could you or samvel check that out?